# missing : after property id

Tags: jquery

I'm a jquery novice..I got missing : after property id error appeared in the firebug console..I don't have much idea what's wrong with this code..

```
$('#mytable tr').click(function(){
   $(this).animate({padding-left: '+=50px'}, 2000);
  }, function(){
   $(this).animate({padding-left: '-=50px'}, 2000);
  });
```

Comment: is it just my eyes? or you are really binding "2 functions" to click?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `padding-left` like this, you either need `"padding-left"` or `paddingLeft` for the property name, like this:

```
$('#mytable tr').toggle(function(){
  $(this).animate({'padding-left': '+=50px'}, 2000);
}, function(){
  $(this).animate({'padding-left': '-=50px'}, 2000);
});
```

Or this:

```
$('#mytable tr').toggle(function(){
  $(this).animate({paddingLeft: '+=50px'}, 2000);
}, function(){
  $(this).animate({paddingLeft: '-=50px'}, 2000);
});
```

In jQuery, anything property passed into [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) with a capital in it [gets replaced with `-lower`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L121), so `paddingLeft` gets converted to `padding-left` under the covers.

*Edit:* As [Reigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251986/reigel) points out in comments, you can't bind multiple functions to `click`, I *think* you meant [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which is what I put above, this swaps between functions on each `click` event.

Comment: is binding two functions on click have effects on the second function?... +1 though for the correct answer.. ;)

Comment: @Reigel - Was editing in your comment just now, updated for this...it works the way he had it, but the second function wouldn't have run.

Comment: thank you guys,i replaced tr with td and it works..don't know why it doesn't work in tr..

Answer (score 0):

`-` isnt valid for literal keys in object declarations. You need to wrap parentheses around any keys with dashes.

Try this:

```
$('#mytable tr').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({"padding-left": '+=50px'}, 2000);
}, function(){
  $(this).animate({"padding-left": '-=50px'}, 2000);
});
```

EDIT: Do you mean to `toggle` instead of `click`?